# Handle jq compiler exceptions in python

Tags: python, json, exception, jq

Hello people I want to execute jq commands, from python, and I tried to install the pyjq module but I didn't succeed. So I decided to run directly with the os module, although it would not be the most correct as mentioned directly in the documentation.
The main idea is from a directory full of json files, iterate through them to form the query to execute extracting the input blob, and the jq filter that is also stored in the json file, but in some cases the jq compiler error is thrown, and I would like to find the exception that allows me to handle it.

I run the following code:

`

```
def open_with_inp():

        generic_json = [
        {
        "color": "red",
        "value": "#f00"
        },
        {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "image":
            {
                "url": "images/0001.jpg",
                "width": 200,
                "height": 200
            },
        "thumbnail":
            {
                "url": "images/thumbnails/0001.jpg",
                "width": 32,
                "height": 32
            }
        },
        [ 100, 500, 300, 200, 400 ]
        ]

        sample_file_nb = input('Enter a number to extract the desired sample data: ')

        sample_name = 'samples' + sample_file_nb + '.json'

        path_search = 'samples/' + sample_name

        with open(path_search) as f:
            
            #At this moment, we have all the data of the original sample, and we test it 
            filesample = json.load(f)

            sample_input = json.dumps(filesample['input'])

            sample_jq_string = json.dumps(filesample['jq_solution'])

            query = f"echo '{sample_input}' | jq {sample_jq_string}"

            try:
                stream = os.popen(query)


                output = stream.read()

                print(output)

                #At this moment we test it with a generic json that is chosen randomly

                print('-'*21,'Test With Random Json', '-'*21)

                json_generic_test = json.dumps(generic_json[random.randint(0, (len(generic_json) -1 ))])
                
                #We build the new query
                query = f"echo '{json_generic_test}' | jq {sample_jq_string}"

                stream = os.popen(query)

                output = stream.read()

                print(output)

            except os.error:
                print('Error')
```

`

This function requests a number from the user and looks for the json file in the directory and then saves its jq-string, to be able to test it in the generic json and define that this jq-string does not depend on its input

Json file format in directory:
`

```
{
  "language":"JSON",
    "input": {
    "time": "2022-04-07T12:53:39.302+0300",
    "user": "Basic PGxvZ2luPg=="
  },

  "jq_solution": ".user |= if startswith(\"Basic\") then .[6:] | @base64d else . end",

  "desired_output": { "time": "2022-04-07T12:53:39.302+0300", "user": "<login>" },

  "task": "Using jq, get all the characters after 'Basic', base64 decode them and replace in input."
  
}
```

`

I would expect to be able to handle jq compiler exceptions, and to be able to count which are the files whose jq-solution is independent of their input.My idea would be to be able to catch the error, to be able to say that if the error is caught the jq query is not applicable to any input

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does `except error:` not catch the error? If it does catch it, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: My idea would be to be able to catch the error, to be able to say that if the error is caught the jq query is not applicable to any input

Comment: But what is your problem? Is the `except` not working? Is no error raised? Is the wrong error raised?

Comment: my 2 cts advice , you are using python a powerful language , you dont need to call jq to do some json works